# UIPanGestureRecognizer inaccurate on iPhone 5s + iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I’m using UIPanGestureRecognizer to pan around in my game (cocos2d 2.0), it’s been working fine, from iOS 5.x to 6.x. Suddenly in iOS 7 it’s getting very choppy. You can pan around for a while, but eventually it becomes inaccurate. Even before my game code does anything with the gesture I can clearly see in my logs that the translation is jumping around 3-5 points. Normally a smooth finger drag only has translation spread out 1 points per change. Swiping near the edges of the screen seems to immediately cause the problem, but just panning causes it as well.

Did anything change that would cause problems with cocos2d? Or the gesture recognizer in general?

Comment: there are apparently some memory leak problems in cocos2d 2.x versions when running on iOS 7, you'll find discussions both here and on the cocos2d forums but atm no solution

Comment: Enough of a memory leak to cause this gesture issue? I'm able to produce the problem very quickly after load. Looks like the memory is more of a slow bleed.

Comment: I haven't followed the thread closely but some say it is about congestion, others experienced it in combination with touch input, others just get a constant increase in memory usage over time though not significant on devices. You may want to check if perhaps your framerate is dropping. Are you maybe adding nodes as a result of panning?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some priority conflict with the CADisplayLink refreshing an openGL view and UIApplication's sendEvent method. I struggled with this for a week!  In my tests I found that a UIPanGestureRecognizer will usually fire with every screen refresh as long as your finger has moved.  When refreshing a GLKView (or any openGL context I'm assuming), every so often the recognizer will skip a few frames. If you hook up a CADisplayLink to refresh a GLKView and pan around you can see it for yourself.

```
-(void)panRecCallback:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)rec{
    CGPoint loc = [panRec locationInView:self.view];
    printf("    rec loc %3.3f %3.3f\n",loc.x,loc.y);
}
-(void)display:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink{
    [myGLKView display];
    CGPoint loc = [panRec locationInView:self.view];
    printf("display loc %3.3f %3.3f\n",loc.x,loc.y);
}
```

I never did get it totally figured out, but I did find a *super* hacky way to get it to work consistently smooth.  I found that during the glitch, the recognizer was waiting on a semaphore, which I took to mean that the openGL's drawing was happening before the recognizer's selector was firing, and that it was somehow lagging just enough to block a cycle. So my goal was to delay the recognizer enough that it will fire before the *next* render. Here's the hack part, I dispatch_async on the main thread the firing of my `[glkView display]` so that my recognizer would get called, and then I capture the recognizers action in a block and fire it after the cycle has passed.  I hate to say that this was all I could do, but I works!